# Passing data from one form from one page and another form second page together to email

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form from page one and another form from page two. What i want is that both forms must send the data together in one single email.i tried to get the information from form one and post it to another page in a variable where the another form is and then send them to email. But the data from page one of form one is lost when i am sending the second form.

Form 1 Page One

```
                <form action="https://investorsolution.com.au/commercial-loan-form-slider/" method="post">
                <div class="refinance_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Loan Amount" id="comaperror" class="number" name="how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="refinance_submit">
                <input type="submit" class="comapnext" value="APPLY NOW" />
                </div>
                </form>
```

Form 2 page 2

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="msform">
            <!-- progressbar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active"></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- fieldsets -->
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Success message -->
                <h1 style="color: #87C550;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    line-height: 50px;
                    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
                    font-weight: 700;">
                            <?php 
                                if(isset($success)){
                                    echo $success;
                                }
                                if(isset($error)){
                                    echo $error;
                                }
                            ?>
                </h1>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Get an Easy Access to Funding</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Are you trading for at least 6 months?</h3>
                <p class="comfmsg1"></p>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                          <input type="radio" name="trading_for_at_least_6_months" value="Yes" id="6_months_yes"/>
                          <label for="6_months_yes" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                            <input type="radio" name="trading_for_at_least_6_months" value="No" id="6_months_no"/>
                            <label for="6_months_no" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">No</label>
                        </div>

                <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext1 action-button" value="Next" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Do you have a revenue of minimum $10,000 per month?</h3>
                <p class="comfmsg2"></p>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                          <input type="radio" name="revenue_of_minimum_10000" value="Yes" id="revenue_minimum_yes"/>
                          <label for="revenue_minimum_yes" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                            <input type="radio" name="revenue_of_minimum_10000" value="Yes" id="revenue_minimum_no"/>
                            <label for="revenue_minimum_no" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">No</label>
                        </div>

                <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext2 action-button" value="Next" />
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous_extra_per previous action-button" value="Back" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Is this loan going to be used for any business purpose?</h3>
                <p class="comfmsg3"></p>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                          <input type="radio" name="used_for_any_business_purpose" value="Yes" id="business_purpos_yes"/>
                          <label for="business_purpos_yes" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                            <input type="radio" name="used_for_any_business_purpose" value="Yes" id="business_purpos_no"/>
                            <label for="business_purpos_no" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">No</label>
                        </div>

                <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext3 action-button" value="Next" />
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous_extra_per previous action-button" value="Back" />
            </fieldset>

        <fieldset style="width:100%;">
                <h2 class="fs-title">Get an Easy Access to Funding</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How long are you in the Business?</h3>
                <p class="comfmsg4"></p>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                          <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="Less than 6 months" id="less_than_6_months" />
                          <label for="less_than_6_months" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">Less than 6 months </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                            <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="6-12 months" id="6_12_months"/>
                            <label for="6_12_months" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">6-12 months</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                          <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="less than 1 year" id="less_than_1_year"/>
                          <label for="less_than_1_year" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">less than 1 year</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                            <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="More than 1 year" id="more_than_1_year"/>
                            <label for="more_than_1_year" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">More than 1 year</label>
                        </div>

                <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext4 action-button" value="Next" />
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous_extra_per previous action-button" value="Back" />
            </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What is your First Name?</h3>
                <p class="msgc5"></p>
                <input type="text" name="con_name" class="text_input" id="error5">
                <br />


                <!-- Button Next/Back -->
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
                <input type="button5" name="next" class="next5 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your Phone Number</h3>
                <p class="msgc6"></p>
                <input type="text" name="con_phone" class="text_input" id="errorc6">
                <br />

                <!-- Button Next/Back -->
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="nextc6 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your Email Address</h3>
                <p class="msgc7"></p>
                <input type="email" name="con_email" class="text_input" id="errorc7">
                <br />

                <!-- Button Next/Back -->
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="nextc7 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What is the Business Trading Name?</h3>
                <p class="msgc8"></p>
                <input type="text" name="trading_name" class="text_input" id="errorc8">
                <br>
                <!-- Button Next/Back -->
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="nextc8 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What is Your Address?</h3>
                <p class="msgcb"></p>
                <input type="text" name="your_address" class="text_input"id="errorcb">
                <br>
                <!-- Button Next/Back -->
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
                <input type="submit" name="con_submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
        </fieldset>

            <div>
        </form>
```

php code of form 2

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['con_submit'])){


    $trading_for_at_least_6_months = $_POST['trading_for_at_least_6_months'];
    $revenue_of_minimum_10000 = $_POST['revenue_of_minimum_10000'];
    $used_for_any_business_purpose = $_POST['used_for_any_business_purpose'];
    $how_long_are_you_in_the_business = $_POST['how_long_are_you_in_the_business'];
    $how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for = $_REQUEST['how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for'];
    $how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for = $_POST['how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for'];
    $con_name = $_POST['con_name'];
    $con_phone = $_POST['con_phone'];
    $con_email = $_POST['con_email'];
    $trading_name = $_POST['trading_name'];
    $your_address = $_POST['your_address'];

    if(!empty($con_name) && !empty($con_email) && !empty($con_phone)){


            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        $con_message = "<table border='1' width='100%'>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>Subject</td>
            <td>Commercial Form</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>Are you trading for at least 6 months?</td>
            <td>$trading_for_at_least_6_months</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>Do you have a revenue of minimum $ 10,000 per month?</td>
            <td>$revenue_of_minimum_10000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>Is this loan going to be used for any business purpose?</td>
            <td>$used_for_any_business_purpose</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>How long are you in the Business?</td>
            <td>$how_long_are_you_in_the_business</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>How long do you need the loan for?</td>
            <td>$how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>What is your First Name?</td>
            <td>$con_name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>Your Phone Number</td>
            <td>$con_phone</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>Your Email Address</td>
            <td>$con_email</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>What is the Business Trading Name?</td>
            <td>$trading_name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='25%'>What is Your Address?</td>
            <td>$your_address</td>
            </tr>
            </table>";

        $mailsent = mail('loans@investorsolution.com.au,xdtaufeeq@gmail.com', 'Commercial Loan Form', $con_message, $headers);

            if($mailsent){
                $success = 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
            }else{
                $error = 'Your message has not been sent.';
            }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Ideally you provide us the code of both forms in order to see the existing code and see what might be the issue.  Its difficult to find the solution without any code.  What I think is that in form 2 you are not creating hidden inputs with data pre-populated with values from first form.

Comment: sorry for not including the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass data from form 1 to form 2 and then include the data submitted in form 1 also in form 2 submission you need to:

- Pass the data from form 1 to form 2 (which you are currently doing correctly)
- Include the data from form 1 also in form 2 in hidden inputs (converting user input to html entities to avoid security issue)

Also please note that you do not need to create an input with `type="text"` and then use `style="display:none;"`.  You can just create an inout with `type="hidden"` and it will be automatically hidden to the user by the browser as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for'])?>" />
```

In your case form 2 should be as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for'])?>" />

    <div id="msform">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Success message -->
            <h1 style="color: #87C550;
                font-size: 25px;
                line-height: 50px;
                font-family: 'Ubuntu';
                font-weight: 700;">
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($success)){
                                echo $success;
                            }
                            if(isset($error)){
                                echo $error;
                            }
                        ?>
            </h1>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Get an Easy Access to Funding</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Are you trading for at least 6 months?</h3>
            <p class="comfmsg1"></p>
                <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                      <input type="radio" name="trading_for_at_least_6_months" value="Yes" id="6_months_yes"/>
                      <label for="6_months_yes" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                        <input type="radio" name="trading_for_at_least_6_months" value="No" id="6_months_no"/>
                        <label for="6_months_no" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">No</label>
                    </div>

            <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext1 action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Do you have a revenue of minimum $10,000 per month?</h3>
            <p class="comfmsg2"></p>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                      <input type="radio" name="revenue_of_minimum_10000" value="Yes" id="revenue_minimum_yes"/>
                      <label for="revenue_minimum_yes" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                        <input type="radio" name="revenue_of_minimum_10000" value="Yes" id="revenue_minimum_no"/>
                        <label for="revenue_minimum_no" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">No</label>
                    </div>

            <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext2 action-button" value="Next" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous_extra_per previous action-button" value="Back" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Is this loan going to be used for any business purpose?</h3>
            <p class="comfmsg3"></p>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                      <input type="radio" name="used_for_any_business_purpose" value="Yes" id="business_purpos_yes"/>
                      <label for="business_purpos_yes" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                        <input type="radio" name="used_for_any_business_purpose" value="Yes" id="business_purpos_no"/>
                        <label for="business_purpos_no" style="padding: 20px 80px !important;">No</label>
                    </div>

            <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext3 action-button" value="Next" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous_extra_per previous action-button" value="Back" />
        </fieldset>

    <fieldset style="width:100%;">
            <h2 class="fs-title">Get an Easy Access to Funding</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How long are you in the Business?</h3>
            <p class="comfmsg4"></p>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                      <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="Less than 6 months" id="less_than_6_months" />
                      <label for="less_than_6_months" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">Less than 6 months </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                        <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="6-12 months" id="6_12_months"/>
                        <label for="6_12_months" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">6-12 months</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">
                      <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="less than 1 year" id="less_than_1_year"/>
                      <label for="less_than_1_year" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">less than 1 year</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_radio_button_custom_two">  
                        <input type="radio" name="how_long_are_you_in_the_business" value="More than 1 year" id="more_than_1_year"/>
                        <label for="more_than_1_year" style="padding: 20px 5px !important;">More than 1 year</label>
                    </div>

            <input type="button" name="next" class="next_extra_per comfnext4 action-button" value="Next" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous_extra_per previous action-button" value="Back" />
        </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What is your First Name?</h3>
            <p class="msgc5"></p>
            <input type="text" name="con_name" class="text_input" id="error5">
            <br />


            <!-- Button Next/Back -->
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
            <input type="button5" name="next" class="next5 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your Phone Number</h3>
            <p class="msgc6"></p>
            <input type="text" name="con_phone" class="text_input" id="errorc6">
            <br />

            <!-- Button Next/Back -->
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
            <input type="button" name="next" class="nextc6 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your Email Address</h3>
            <p class="msgc7"></p>
            <input type="email" name="con_email" class="text_input" id="errorc7">
            <br />

            <!-- Button Next/Back -->
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
            <input type="button" name="next" class="nextc7 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What is the Business Trading Name?</h3>
            <p class="msgc8"></p>
            <input type="text" name="trading_name" class="text_input" id="errorc8">
            <br>
            <!-- Button Next/Back -->
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
            <input type="button" name="next" class="nextc8 action-button" value="Next" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What is Your Address?</h3>
            <p class="msgcb"></p>
            <input type="text" name="your_address" class="text_input"id="errorcb">
            <br>
            <!-- Button Next/Back -->
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" style="margin-left: 28%;"/>
            <input type="submit" name="con_submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" style="margin-right: 28%;" />
    </fieldset>

        <div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 aproaches in this scenario:

Option 1:

> You store the data from form#1 into a session or database. and just retrieve the stored input when generating the email.

Option 2:

> You send the input from the form#1 as prefilled hidden input fields on form#2 back to the user so the second post/get request will have all the data from both forms.

Option 3:

> Combine both forms into one.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it thanks omar tani. i didnt populate the form right way. found this and solved it

```
<input type="text" name="how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['how_long_do_you_need_the_loan_for'])?>" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: Glad that you managed to sort it out. I will add my answer to this question so you can set it as solved :) Thanks